# Separate WordPress-generated content into two divs

Tags: php, jquery, html, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm trying to convert a static HTML site into a WordPress theme. At the moment, there is the following (static) code:

```
<div class="postwrap">
    <div class="first-col">

        <!-- Post Description -->
         <h1>Post Title</h1>
        <p>Post description. At essimag nimilib errorum fuga. Harunt faci aut elitatur.</p>

    </div>
    <div class="second-col">

        <!-- Post Images -->
        <img src="images/placeholder.png" alt="This is a photo">

    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, all the content in `first-col` is text-based. All the content in `second-col` are images, and WordPress simply uses `<?php get_content(); ?>` grab this content.

Is there a way I can sort images submitted into a separate div, such as `second-col`? I'm aware this can be done with jQuery, but I'm wondering if there's a method with PHP or WordPress.

Comment: Here is a link: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_content. Is that what you meant?

Comment: Are you want to separate a `post content` including text & images into 2 columns?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can display any images that have been uploaded/attached to a post/page by using the following code.

```
<div class="second-col">

    <?php
    // Get all images uploaded/attached to this post/page.
    if (
        $images = get_posts(
            array(

                'post_parent'       =>  get_the_ID(),
                'post_type'         =>  'attachment',
                'post_mime_type'    =>  'image',
                'orderby'           =>  'menu_order',
                'order'             =>  'ASC'

                )
            )
        ) :

    // Loop through the results and display each full-size image.
    foreach( $images as $image ) :
        echo wp_get_attachment_image( $image->ID, 'full' );
    endforeach;

    endif;
    ?>

</div>
```

`get_posts()` is a WordPress function that returns an array of posts based on the parameters we pass to it. We then loop through that array and call the `wp_get_attachment_image()` function on each value in it. `wp_get_attachment_image()` is another WordPress function that returns an HTML image element.

In order to display the images only in the second column, do NOT insert them into the post/page. Simply upload them from the post/page edit screen then close the modal window and update the post/page. You could also upload images from the media library and attach them to the post/page you want.

Comment: Thanks. Could you possibly explain the logic used in the PHP code. Is `get_posts()` a built in WordPress function?

Comment: @tmyie I added some explanation to my answer, if this works for you please don't forget to mark it as the accepted answer :-) Thanks!